# is it possible to make two base_url() for separate urls?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got some nasty blow bcz there are two codeigniter projects 1st one is handling all separate back end for uploading images and 2nd one is just loading images. The reason for this that both are big in size so team decided to do separate one.
For this reason both have separate base_urls which is now i m getting hard wt shd i do in order to setup url for making base_url2 or something like that.

The base_url for 1st codeigniter folder is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/Burea/';
```

and for 2nd one is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/ATC/';
```

Now the images folder is in Burea folder which i want to access by just placing another custom base_url something like:

```
<img style="height: 177px;width: 200px;" src="<?php echo base_url().'uploadsimages'.'/'.$lrd1->picturename;?>" alt="...">
```

should access uploadsimages folder of **Burea** containing images. Is it possible ?

Comment: Why not make the base URL `http://localhost:8080/` and do `base_url() . 'ATC/foo/bar'`?

Comment: oh great thanks.... i dont know why i did nt think abt.
+1 vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, CodeIgniter has one primary config file, located at application/config/config.php. If you open the file using your text editor you’ll see that config items are stored in an array called $config.

You can add your own config items to this file, or if you prefer to keep your configuration items separate (assuming you even need config items), simply create your own file and save it in config folder.

The base_url for 1st codeigniter folder is:

```
$config['base_url_burea'] = 'http://localhost:8080/Burea/';
```

and for 2nd one is:

```
$config['base_url_atc'] = 'http://localhost:8080/ATC/';
```

Now the images folder is in Burea folder which i want to access by just placing another custom base_url something like:

```
<img style="height: 177px;width: 200px;" src="<?php echo base_url_burea().'uploadsimages'.'/'.$lrd1->picturename;?>" alt="...">
```